# IOS Payload Size

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, payload

Does anybody know what is the actual size of Payload attributes for iOS? I keep getting SQL error for any of these columns. I am trying to insert PayloadDesc, PayloadDisplayName, etc to these column. And apparently the actual data do not fit with the column. I dont know the actual data size since these information are generated by apple, but the documentation does not specify the attributes size.

- PayloadDescription --> VARCHAR(512)
- PayloadDisplayName --> VARCHAR(256)
- PayloadIdentifier --> VARCHAR(128)
- PayloadOrganization --> VARCHAR(64)

SQLError: ExecuteSQL returned status: -1 State: 22001 Native: 0 Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation

```
INSERT INTO #NewProfileList ( .. ) SQLError: ExecuteSQL returned status: -1 State: 22001 Native: 0 Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation
```

This is the document. Thanks for the help!

[iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf)

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? It's a bit puzzling to see the iOS Configuration Profile documentation alongside a Microsoft SQL Server exception.

Comment: ah I am sorry.. let me edit that